# In PonyORM is it possible to split the definition of an entity?

Tags: python-3.x, ponyorm

I want to split up the definition of an entity class, i.e. add columns after I initially declared the class (but before I generate the mapping). Is this at all possible?

I've reduced my problem to this example code below. It throws a `pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Reverse attribute for Passport.person not found` on the generation of the mapping. When I put `passport = Optional("Passport")` in the class definition everything works but I want to split the *passport* part from the pure *person* part.

I understand that the answer might just be: "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from pony.orm import *


db = Database()

### PART 1: Person ###
class Person(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)


### PART 2: Passport (belonging to a Person)  ###
Person.passport = Optional("Passport")

class Passport(db.Entity):
    person = Required("Person")


db.bind("sqlite", ":memory:")
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```

Comment: In the end I spend a lot more time drilling down to the actual problem to get to this short example than actually solving the problem. Again it turns out finding the true problem gets you a long way.

Comment: Hi Bert! Why do you want to do this, what is your motivation?

Comment: Hi Alexander! I'm trying to write a modular application, i.e. an application from which I can have a 'basic' version and a version with extra modules added. So in this fictitious example one where you can manage people (basic) and one where you can also register the passports (with the passport module as extra).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer depends on the use-case. In your comment you told that you want to have a "basic" and an "advanced" version of your application. In that case I suggest to use entity inheritance:

```py
########## basic.py ##########
from pony.orm import *

db = Database()

class Person(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    contacts = Set("Contact")
    classtype = Discriminator(str)

class Contact(db.Entity):
    person = Required(Person)
    type = Required(str)
    value = Required(str)

########## advanced.py ##########
from basic import *

class ExtendedPerson(Person):
    passport = Optional("Passport")

class Passport(db.Entity):
    person = Required(ExtendedPerson)
    code = Required(str, unique=True)

########## main.py ##########
from advanced import *
import settings

db.bind('postgres', **settings.db_params)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

with db_session:
    john = ExtendedPerson(name='John')
    p = Passport(person=john, code='123-456')
```

The `Discriminator` column is a system column that is used for inheritance. Pony stores all subclasses in the same table and determines the subclass of specific instance looking at that column's value. Typically Pony adds this column automatically, but if it is possible that you sometimes will import just `basic` module Pony will not know about existence of the `ExtendedPerson` subclass and will not add that attribute to entity definition automatically.

Another use-case is when you take a third-party module which was written by another developer and want to extend its functionality. For that case we plan to add the possibility to define relation just in one entity, which are defined later. When we add such functionality, you will be able to define a relation just in `Passport` entity, the example syntax is:

class Person(db.Entity):
        name = Required(str)

```
class Passport(db.Entity):
    person = Required("Person",
        reverse='passport', reverse_attr=Optional("Passport"))
    code = Required(str, unique=True)
```

Right now Pony has no such functionality, but we can add it in the near future

Comment: Thanks Alexander! I'll have a look at the inheritance. The extending of functionality seems to fit my use-case the most. Looking forward to the future of PonyORM.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the source code of PonyORM and some trial and error I've found what I can do to make it work. Though I'm not sure this is *official* and if everything is needed. So I'm not sure this will still work in future versions.

**The code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from pony.orm import *


db = Database()

### PART 1: Person ###
class Person(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(unicode)


### PART 2: Passport (belonging to a Person)  ###
extra_column = Optional("Passport", reverse='person')
extra_column._init_(Person, 'passport')
Person._attrs_.append(extra_column)
Person._new_attrs_.append(extra_column)
Person._adict_['passport'] = extra_column
Person.passport = extra_column


class Passport(db.Entity):
    person = Required("Person", reverse='passport')


db.bind("sqlite", ":memory:")
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```